# Creating a unique index for a collection in reactivemongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

Looking at the MongoDB documentation it looks like you can ensure an index is created for a collection at application runtime using a command that looks something like this:

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex({'my-col': 1}, {unique: true})
```

I can't find anything like this in the reactive mongo apis. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the IndexManager from your BSONCollection:

```
collection.indexesManager.ensure(...)
```

See reactivemongo docs for details:

- [0.9](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.9/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.indexes.CollectionIndexesManager) (as of Jan 2019 - gives 404)
- [0.1x](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/api/reactivemongo/api/indexes/IndexesManager.html) (as of Jan 2019 - current version)

Comment: please mention one sample for creating index and also for remove index using reactive-mongo

Comment: link is not valid

Answer (score 0):

As of libraryDependencies += "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.20.3-play28"

1st define the index

```
val createdTSInx = Index(
  key = Seq("createdTS" -> IndexType.Ascending),
  name = Some("createdTSInx"),
  unique = true,
  background = false,
  sparse = false,
  expireAfterSeconds = None,
  storageEngine = None,
  weights = None,
  defaultLanguage = None,
  languageOverride = None,
  textIndexVersion = None,
  sphereIndexVersion = None,
  bits = None,
  min = None,
  max = None,
  bucketSize = None,
  collation = None,
  wildcardProjection = None,
  version = None,
  partialFilter = None,
  options = BSONDocument.empty)
```

// to create

```
  collection.indexesManager.create(createdTSInx)
```

//to ensure

```
  collection.indexesManager.ensure(createdTSInx)
```